# Graph API insights/page_fans_by_like_source end_time change

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm using developers.facebook.com graph API to test v2.2 calls.

When calling for example:

`[PAGE-ID]/insights/page_fans_by_like_source?since=2015-01-09&until=2015-01-10`

or

`[PAGE-ID]/insights/page_fans_by_like_source?since=1420761600&until=1420848000`

I have data returned and values part looks like this:

```
"values": [
    {
      "value": {
        "sponsored_story": 1,
        "page_profile": 1
      },
      "end_time": "2015-01-09T08:00:00+0000"
    }
  ],
```

For obvious reasons this is not the correct data from my point of view since "end_time" is set on 8:00:00 hour so we have only data from 2015-01-09 00:00:00 till 2015-01-09 08:00:00. Of course I'm looking for data till midnight. **How I can change this behavior?**

**I know that I can format "end_time" but how to change those hours? Is this even possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Metrics that are marked with * are available in real-time, i.e., they are refreshed approximately every 15 minutes. Most other metrics will update once every 24 hours.

[Source: Graph API Reference v2.2 Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights)

Scroll down to "Available Metrics" last bullet under "Naming Patterns for Metrics"

The metric you are looking for is computed once every day as it is not marked with an `*`. The 8am time you are getting is just the time it was computed and is more specific data then you are requesting. You'll just have to ignore it.